# Website breaking at partial pixel width

Tags: css, html

I'm working on a website that is a series of squares at an 8th of the screen size. I used calc, as well as a fallback percent at 12.5%. That 8th width is causing the blocks to try and fill in partial pixel widths, of course it rounds and that breaks my grid. Below is the code I am using to make the website (a partial of the HTML), and 4 images show it the way it should be, breaking, the way it should be, and then breaking again. The float left is used to eliminate the inherent margin that comes with . I would be fine with a 1px line of background at these broken screen sizes, but I want the grid to stay in tact. What can I do to prevent this?

This is the live site: http://shoutgraphicdesigns.com/

[CORRECT WIDTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya2iq.jpg)

[BROKEN WIDTH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0E6c.jpg)

[CORRECT WIDTH EXAMPLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQw6X.jpg)

[BROKEN WIDTH EXAMPLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caku1.jpg)

```css
.navblock {
 width: 12.5vw; /**fallback**/
 width: calc(100%  /8);
 height: 12.5vw; /**fallback**/
 height: calc(100%  /8);
 display: inline-block;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}
.homethumb img {
 width: 12.5%; /**fallback**/
 width: calc(100%  /8);
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/48_full.png" data-lightbox="localfmjune2nd" data-title="LocalFM 06/02/2017"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/48_thumb.png" title="LocalFM 06/02/2017" alt="LocalFM Poster"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/47_full.png" data-lightbox="front2017" data-title="Shout! Graphics Buisness Card (Front) 2017"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/47_thumb.png" title="Shout! Graphics Buisness Card (Front) 2017" alt="Buisness Card (Front) 2017"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/46_full.png" data-lightbox="back2017" data-title="Shout! Graphics Buisness Card (Back) 2017"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/46_thumb.png" title="Shout! Graphics Buisness Card (Back) 2017" alt="Buisness Card (Back) 2017"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/45_full.png" data-lightbox="maldefposter" data-title="MALDEF Support Poster Concept"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/45_thumb.png" title="MALDEF Support Poster Concept" alt="MALDEF Support Poster"/></a>
  <div class="navblock"> 
   <h2><a href="about.html"><br>ABOUT<br>ME</a></h2>
  </div>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/44_full.png" data-lightbox="fluxsep5th" data-title="Flux Capacitor 09/05/2016"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/44_thumb.png" title="Flux Capacitor 09/05/2016" alt="Flux Capacitor Poster 09/05/2016"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/43_full.gif" data-lightbox="fluxsep27th" data-title="Flux Capacitor 09/27/2016"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/43_thumb.gif" title="Flux Capacitor 09/27/2016" alt="Flux Capacitor Poster 09/27/2016"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/42_full.png" data-lightbox="fluxsep9th" data-title="Flux Capacitor 09/09/2016"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/42_thumb.png" title="Flux Capacitor 09/09/2016" alt="Flux Capacitor Poster 09/09/2016"/></a>
  <a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/41_full.png" data-lightbox="julyfreeflier" data-title="July Free Flier Offer 2016"><img src="files/images/portfolio/thumb/41_thumb.png" title="July Free Flier Offer 2016" alt="July Free Flier Poster Offer 2016"/></a>
  <div class="navblock"> 
   <h2><a href="files/images/portfolio/full_size/46_full.png" data-lightbox="back2017" data-title="Shout! Graphics Buisness Card (Back) 2017"><br>CONTACT<br>ME</a></h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you always using the same number of squares?

Comment: No, that's why I avoided using grid, or table cell. I also wanted to avoid using space holder PNGs. I didn't want to avoid adding portfolio pieces until I had enough for the next row, so I kept it fluid.